# Additional message for passed spec in Jasmine

Tags: javascript, jasmine

There is a reasonable (yet undocumented) [way to provide an explanation](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/641#issuecomment-54736801) for failed spec

```
it('should be ok', function () {
    expect(foo).toBeDefined('and btw, foo is', foo);
});
```

And [other solution](https://github.com/avrelian/jasmine2-custom-message) is aimed at failed specs as well.

Is there possibility (including third-party code) to provide meaningful output for **passed specs** in spec list, other than modifying spec titles?

I would consider this as graphic alternative to `console.log`.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I'm interested to know why you want to do this?

Comment: You could write your own [custom matcher](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/custom_matcher.html)...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Can you give an example how custom matcher would output additional info next to the passed spec?

Comment: @JamesThorpe To provide more informational output in browser that gives an idea what's going on in specs without digging too deep into the code or the console.

Comment: The link provided has an example of just that.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan It provides `message` for failed tests, not for passed.

Comment: Your suite description plus your test message should be verbose enough to tell you WHY a test passed or failed without any additional message. If it isn't, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Console.log() is a very bad practice because your logged info turn up in your test reports.

Comment: I also would like to have additional messages for passed specs in my custom matcher. If I return {pass: true, message:'foo'}, the message 'foo' will not be shown. My custom matcher except(actualArray).toInclude(['first','second']) would list all items for which the spec has been passed. This way, somebody who looks at the test does not only see that the test passed but also see what items ('first', 'second') has been tested for. Of course I could write a single spec for each item but that would cause a lot of repeating "dummy code".